# Is there any place that I can find words whose spelling looks opposite to its own meaning?

Tags: contradiction

I am preparing for GRE exam and I found there are words that looks opposite to its meaning. For example, the word "restive" actually means "unrest" and the word "factitious" actually means "not actual fact". I am wondering if there is a classification name for such words and/or is there any websites where I can find a list of such words.

Comment: You could buy a thesaurus. Roget's is a famous one. Alternatively, you can look up synonyms and antonyms on-line using http://www.thesaurus.com. This is based on Roget's Thesaurus.

Comment: Hi Mick, I am sorry if the title looked confusing. I have updated it to be more clear. What I want is not antonym to a word but words whose spelling implies an opposite meaning to its actual meaning.(Such words must be carefully remembered for my exam)

Comment: Do you mean like *inflammable*, which means the same thing as *flammable* (the opposite of which is *non-flammable*)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Of course you do. I should have read your question more carefully.

Comment: Arrgh! We really need the technical term for such a word. I think we'll just have to wait for an expert to drop by.

Comment: Got it! They are known as [*antiautonyms*](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/fun/wordplay/antiauto.html).

Comment: Like invaluable or priceless.

Comment: There's also "pitted" which means with no pits.

Comment: @DAE Not necessarily, that only applies to food products like cherries and olives (and is synonomous with 'stoned' which is another example). However 'pitted' can also mean 'damaged by pitting' as in "the shot-blasted plate was badly pitted".